# How to use my own login credential to authorize in wso2 oauth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am reading the OAuth2 with WSO2 Playground example which is provided [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/OAuth+2.0+with+WSO2+Playground).
In this example, I use **admin/admin** as user credential to login and allow Playground2 client access the photos (user resource). But this credential (admin/admin) belong to wso2 oauth2 server.

The problem is that, if I have my running webapp, using my own mysql db to store thousands username/password, **how could I config wso2 oauth server use this db, and apply oauth2 for my own app as the Playground2?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Identity server is using an embedded LDAP as the userstore and the users are authenticated against that. 
If you need to change the userstore to one of your own userstore (A DB with custom schema in your case), you need to [write a custom user store manager](http://isurad.blogspot.com/2016/03/how-to-write-custom-user-store-manager.html) and point it as a userstore for Identity Server.

Comment: Thanks for your help.